Can photons be seen in a superconductor?
In the video Electromagnetism as a Gauge Theory, Richard Behiel states that electromagnetism is a result of adding local phase symmetry to the Dirac equation. He also says (at 3h9m) that this phase symmetry is broken in superconductors, leading to a number of weird effects, including photons gaining mass.
Einstein famously asked the question "What would a photon look like if we were in its rest-frame?" and the answer was, it has no rest-frame because it has no mass. But if photons have mass in superconductors, wouldn't that mean they then have a rest-frame?
So my questions are:

Is it true that photons gain mass in superconductors?
If so, does this mean they have a rest-frame?
If so, does this mean we could potentially see a photon (maybe using similar techniques to the ones used to photograph individual atoms) ?


You should perhaps read a textbook in the London equation. It will explain why such things are said.

When a photon gets inside a material, the resultant quasiparticle is a polariton and should not be confused with a photon in vacuum. Its behaviour is altered so much that, if we are sloppy and still call them photons, then a lot of unnecessary paradoxes would arise just from the sloppy language. Instead, using polaritons would immediately make it clear that there is nothing particularly paradoxical. It is not paradoxical in superconductors, just as it is not paradoxical in any other material.

Great question! :) My next video will cover this in depth.
It's a nuanced topic. Basically what happens is that the superconducting condensate can be described by a complex scalar field psi (Ginzburg-Landau model). When the temperature of a superconductor drops below Tc and the condensate forms, it takes on a nonzero value, which necessarily has some phase. In that way, it spontaneously breaks global phase symmetry.
Regarding local phase symmetry, the effect is more subtle. It's the Anderson-Higgs mechanism.  Basically what happens is that it costs energy to have phase gradients in psi, so the condensate wants to be as uniform in phase as possible.  But you can imagine having ripples in the phase, with some energy, and those would be Nambu-Goldstone modes, like we see with phonons and magnons, whenever a global phase symmetry is broken, you'll typically find that the system hosts waves in the degree of freedom of the broken symmetry, and those waves should be massless.
However, in a superconductor, phase waves are exactly the kind of thing that can be gauged away, by applying the transformation exp(-i*theta), where theta(x,t) is the rippling phase angle of the condensate. So when we gauge away that phase, we're hopping into the "unitary gauge".  But the energy contained in those NG modes, the phase waves, now pops out as contributions to the vector potential A, which gives it a form of energy that it usually doesn't have. This ends up allowing A to host longitudinal modes, whereas usually A only hosts transverse modes. So we get an additional degree of freedom, and this gives mass to A. The photon mass can be calculated by evaluating the kinetic term of the Ginzburg-Landau free energy density in the unitary gauge, and extracting the term proportional to |A|^2.
Whether this makes it possible to observe photons in a superconductor, that's a good question. To first-order approximation, photons just don't go into a superconductor; inside a superconductor, A in the unitary gauge relaxes strongly to 0, which yields the Meissner effect, London equations, and the phenomenology of superconductivity in general. However, A can be disturbed some distance lambda from the surface, where lambda is 50-500 nm, the London penetration depth, the lengthscale over which magnetic fields are expelled from the material.
Because the Anderson-Higgs mechanism gives A mass, i.e. gives rise to a form of energy which is proportional to |A|^2, when the field is quantized, this corresponds to a mass gap on the THz scale. And this suppresses rippling in the NG phase waves, as well as A (bear in mind the NG modes are absorbed into A in the unitary gauge). So this makes the interior of a superconductor quite a boring place, flux vortices notwithstanding. But the reason I bring that up is that, in order to force photons into a superconductor, you'd need them to be super high frequency, THz or higher (above the plasma frequency of the material). This is often described as "the Anderson-Higgs mechanism lifts the NG modes to the plasma frequency".
Anyway, there's a lot more to it, but it's a super fascinating topic.  The next video is gonna be like 4-5 hours long, probably.  I have like 3.5 hours done so far. Hoping to upload in like a month.
Edit: someone wanted to edit my answer to take out the reference to the video, but just to clarify, I'm the guy who made the video that the OP linked to. So I just included that for context, as in like, hey I saw you asked a question about my video, so here's my two cents :)

Yes, photons gain a mass in a superconductor, but it also means that the EM field decay very quickly when it tries to enter a superconductor. For that reason, it is very difficult to get a photon inside a superconductor. Moreover, the idea of a rest frame for a photon inside a superconductor is just an abstract notion. One cannot put an observer inside a superconductor and then boost it to the velocity of a photon so that it can be in that photon's rest frame.

Just want to say that you can have polariton at rest in lab frame.  No boosting required.
